# Formatting the data in row pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I am supposed to format the data of a column.
Data looks like

> test_segment_withcountry-Country:BARBADOS,AFGHANISTAN,ALGERIA,BAHAMAS,AZERBAIJAN,AUSTRIA;Do
>   you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:No;Title Level:Chief
>   Data Officer,Chief Customer Service Officer;Will these Contacts be
>   used in Email Campaign:Yes;test_all_region-Do you want to include
>   Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:Yes;Region:NA,APAC,EMEA,JAPAN,LAD;Will
>   these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:No;

This is the value of a single field.after every semicolon,it should go to next line.

i tried,
with test as

```
(select 'test_segment_withcountry-Country:BARBADOS,AFGHANISTAN,ALGERIA,BAHAMAS,AZERBAIJAN,AUSTRIA;Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:No;Title Level:Chief Data Officer,Chief Customer Service Officer;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:Yes;test_all_region-Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:Yes;Region:NA,APAC,EMEA,JAPAN,LAD;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:No;' col from rp_segment_master where sm_id=254)
    select regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
    from test
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^;]+')) + 1;
```

but this will have different rows but I want it to be a single field.
I know I am ambiguous here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Replace` is what you need; you simply have to understand whether you need to use `chr(10)` or `chr(13)||chr(10)`, depending if you are on Windows or not.

[Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:72412348057) says:

> On Unix, LINEFEED (chr(10)) is the "end of line" marker. Bill long ago
>   decided that on DOS, CARRIAGE RETURN/LINEFEED (chr(13)||chr(10))
>   should be the end of line marker.

So, you may need:

```
with test(s) as ( select 'test_segment_withcountry-Country:BARBADOS,AFGHANISTAN,ALGERIA,BAHAMAS,AZERBAIJAN,AUSTRIA;Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:No;Title Level:Chief Data Officer,Chief Customer Service Officer;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:Yes;test_all_region-Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:Yes;Region:NA,APAC,EMEA,JAPAN,LAD;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:No;' from dual)
select replace (s, ';', chr(10))
from test;
```

or

```
with test(s) as ( select 'test_segment_withcountry-Country:BARBADOS,AFGHANISTAN,ALGERIA,BAHAMAS,AZERBAIJAN,AUSTRIA;Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:No;Title Level:Chief Data Officer,Chief Customer Service Officer;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:Yes;test_all_region-Do you want to include Oracle 2000 C-Level Contacts:Yes;Region:NA,APAC,EMEA,JAPAN,LAD;Will these Contacts be used in Email Campaign:No;' from dual)
select replace (s, ';', chr(13) || chr(10))
from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

For new line in oracle sql, use **chr(10)**

You can replace '**,**' symbol to **chr(10)**

```
select replace('BARBADOS,AFGHANISTAN,ALGERIA,BAHAMAS', ',', chr(10))  from dual
```

[image]

Or if you want split then split function will help you. And It will give result in rows. If you want show it in one row,you can use **[LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)**  function.

```
create or replace type split_tbl as table of varchar2(32767);


create or replace function split
(
    p_list varchar2,
    p_del varchar2 := ','
) return split_tbl pipelined
is
    l_idx    pls_integer;
    l_list    varchar2(32767) := p_list;
    l_value    varchar2(32767);
begin
    loop
        l_idx := instr(l_list,p_del);
        if l_idx > 0 then
            pipe row(substr(l_list,1,l_idx-1));
            l_list := substr(l_list,l_idx+length(p_del));

        else
            pipe row(l_list);
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return;
end split;
```

With this function, You can run a query like this:

```
 select * from table(split('one,two,three'));
```

Here some string aggregation examples:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for showing it one row but in different lines. not different rows.In a row but with multiple lines.

Comment: For new line aggragate rows with chr(10)

Comment: or you can easily replace ","  symbol to chr(10)  and it will give desired output

Comment: select replace('ab,cd',',',chr(10))from dual; This does not give me the desired result.

Comment: I attached and image to answer, look pls.

Comment: @user3165555 why does not replace give the right result? What's wrong in the result of the replace?

Comment: I am sorry, but the expected result not should like ab cd which is output of replace function, i want it in separate lines but should be in a value of single field. I may be expecting the  impossible but i want to know whether it is possible

Comment: it works, copy result and paste to text file,and you will see result

Comment: Sorry again, I want it to display in new line. I am considered about the display here. Mostly the formatting, show I cant copy ,paste .since this is feed to java procedure for displaying. Thank you